# Get main data from a Database on CouchDB

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase-lite

I am working with `CouchDb` + `CouchBase Lite` on Android but  I have a lot of troubles while I am monitoring the replication. Sometimes It finishs before all the data has been transfered.

In the order hand if you type on your browers (if you use couchbd of course)
http://1xx.xxx.xxx.x:5984/your_dataBase  you will get something like this:

> {"db_name":"your_dataBase","doc_count":23123,"doc_del_count":4812312,"update_seq":1050713,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":2598379649,"data_size":1231223,"instance_start_time":"14123213127176","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":1050713}

More or less I can know the documents numer with this value, so in my client code I can compare that number with the documents I have

> "doc_del_count":4812312

But I don't know how to access to that `json` "main" data, please note that  http://184.xxx.xxx.x:xxxx/your_dataBase has a user and a password.

So my question is: How I can get that CouchDB data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a Basic Authetification with you main DB url, let´s say

> xxx.xxx.x.xx:5984/youDB

The code:

```
final String basicAuth =
                        Base64.encodeToString("yourUser:yourPass"
                                .getBytes(), Base64.NO_WRAP).replace("\n", "");

                URL url = new URL(PreferenceManager.getCouchdbserver());
                URLConnection urlc = url.openConnection();
                HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urlc.getURL().toString());
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic "+basicAuth);
                //HttpReponse response.....and all that stuff
```